# buagent process has been consuming 100% cpu for two days

Tags: linux, restore, process, cpu-usage

The buagent process has been using 100% of cpu since two days ago. I want to terminate this process but I don't know if it's something dangerous or not (I am not much advanced in working with linux, indeed I am very beginner). The only thing that I know is that this process is probably restoring some files. But I think it is not normal for that to take more than two days. Now, do you think it would be OK if I kill this process? What command could I use to do that?
I appreciate any help :)

p.s. We are hosting a few web sites there. This server is also our Name Server and Mail Server as well. A couple of months a go we had a problem with the server which made us to take a full-backup of all files and then reinstall linux. Yesterday, I selected one of the directories on the backup server and restored that directory to a tmp directory on our linux server. After that, I couldn't restore any other directory because every time I want to do that, it says that there is another restore job running and I have to wait for that. When I use the "top" command I can see that the buagent process is consuming 100% of cpu. So I guess that is the problem. I don't know why it has been taking too long to execute.

Comment: What process? How dangerous it may be demends a lot of WHAT is running there.

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were restoring a job to a tmp directory and you're pretty sure that's what this process is from, I would just kill it.  If you kill the agent, you might have to restart it with an init script.  You might try to locate that script before you do kill it.  I can't see an active, properly functioning restore using 100% CPU for 2 days.

If you want to try to find out more info, you can see what files buagent has open using lsof.

```
sudo lsof -p <pid>
```

You can also attach to the process and see what its doing at a system call level using strace:

```
sudo strace -p <pid>
```

Use Ctrl-C to get out of the strace.

Comment: Thank you, I killed it and started it again with this command: /etc/init.d/buagent start